# I upgrade react-native version 0.64.4 to 0.71.12 and getting error when I run my app

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle, build.gradle

I have upgrade react-native version ***0.64.4*** to ***0.71.12*** After doing everthing
I am getting error like this.
An error occured and it says Could not read script react-native\packages\react-native-gradle-plugin' as it does not exist.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Included build 'F:\geminishaleNEW\React_native_version_update\Mobile\node_modules\react-native\packages\react-native-gradle-plugin' does not exist.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

I followed [React Native Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.64.4&to=0.71.12)

**android/build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
       classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.5.1")
       classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")

    }
}


def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }
}
```

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
* This is the configuration block to customize your React Native Android app.
* By default you don't need to apply any configuration, just uncomment the lines you need.
*/
 react {
    /* Folders */
    //   The root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives. Default is '..'
    // root = file("../")
    //   The folder where the react-native NPM package is. Default is ../node_modules/react-native
    // reactNativeDir = file("../node_modules/react-native")
    //   The folder where the react-native Codegen package is. Default is ../node_modules/@react-native/codegen
    // codegenDir = file("../node_modules/@react-native/codegen")
    //   The cli.js file which is the React Native CLI entrypoint. Default is ../node_modules/react-native/cli.js
    // cliFile = file("../node_modules/react-native/cli.js")
    /* Variants */
    //   The list of variants to that are debuggable. For those we're going to
    //   skip the bundling of the JS bundle and the assets. By default is just 'debug'.
    //   If you add flavors like lite, prod, etc. you'll have to list your debuggableVariants.
    // debuggableVariants = ["liteDebug", "prodDebug"]
    /* Bundling */
    //   A list containing the node command and its flags. Default is just 'node'.
    // nodeExecutableAndArgs = ["node"]
    //
    //   The command to run when bundling. By default is 'bundle'
    // bundleCommand = "ram-bundle"
    //
    //   The path to the CLI configuration file. Default is empty.
    // bundleConfig = file(../rn-cli.config.js)
    //
    //   The name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
    // bundleAssetName = "MyApplication.android.bundle"
    //
    //   The entry file for bundle generation. Default is 'index.android.js' or 'index.js'
    // entryFile = file("../js/MyApplication.android.js")
    //
    //   A list of extra flags to pass to the 'bundle' commands.
    //   See https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/docs/commands.md#bundle
    // extraPackagerArgs = []
    /* Hermes Commands */
    //   The hermes compiler command to run. By default it is 'hermesc'
    // hermesCommand = "$rootDir/my-custom-hermesc/bin/hermesc"
    //
    //   The list of flags to pass to the Hermes compiler. By default is "-O", "-output-source-map"
    // hermesFlags = ["-O", "-output-source-map"]
}
/**
* Set this to true to Run Proguard on Release builds to minify the Java bytecode.
*/

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false
/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore (JSC)
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US. Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
 def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

// project.ext.react = [
//     entryFile: "index.js",
//     enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
// ]

//apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"



android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }

    namespace "com.rndiffapp"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.geminishalesolutions.gemini"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 52
        versionName "5.0"
        /**
        * PROD
        * versionCode 22
        * versionName "2.2"
        */
    }
    dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
    
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        test {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        training {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('GEMINITRACKER_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(GEMINITRACKER_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword GEMINITRACKER_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias GEMINITRACKER_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword GEMINITRACKER_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        // dev version
        dev {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", defaultConfig.applicationId
        }
        // test version
        tst {
            applicationIdSuffix ".test"
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", defaultConfig.applicationId
        }
        // training version
        train {
            applicationIdSuffix ".train"
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", defaultConfig.applicationId
        }
        // uat version.
        uat {
            applicationIdSuffix ".uat"
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", defaultConfig.applicationId
        }
        prod {
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", defaultConfig.applicationId
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.instabug.library:instabug:11.6.0'
    implementation project(':react-native-appearance')
    implementation project(':react-native-ble-plx')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_netinfo')
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'
   

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation files('libs\\commons-io-2.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\commons-lang3-3.4.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\commons-net-3.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\commons-validator-1.4.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\core-1.53.0.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\httpcore-4.3.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\httpmime-4.3.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\jackson-core-2.2.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\opencsv-2.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\pkix-1.53.0.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\prov-1.53.0.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\snmp6_1z.jar')
    implementation files('libs\\ZSDK_ANDROID_API.jar')
    implementation project(':react-native-html-to-pdf')
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")

    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
        
        // internalImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
        // trainingImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
        // uatImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
       
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}


apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

***setting.gradle***

```
rootProject.name = ''
include ':react-native-appearance'
project(':react-native-appearance').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-appearance/android')
include ':react-native-ble-plx'
project(':react-native-ble-plx').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-ble-plx/android')
include ':@react-native-community_netinfo'
project(':@react-native-community_netinfo').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/netinfo/android')
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
include ':react-native-html-to-pdf'
project(':react-native-html-to-pdf').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,'../node_modules/react-native-html-to-pdf/android')

includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native/packages/react-native-gradle-plugin')
```

***gradle-wrapepr.properties***

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you encountered seems to indicate that the `react-native-gradle-plugin` is not found or included properly. Here are a few steps you can follow to resolve the issue:

```
 npm install @react-native-community/cli-platform-android
```

1. React Native Gradle Plugin Include:
   In your `android/settings.gradle` file, include the `react-native-gradle-plugin` like this:

   ```
     includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native/packages/react-native-gradle-plugin')
   ```
2. Clean and Rebuild:

   ```
    cd android
   ./gradlew clean
    cd ..
    npx react-native run-android
   ```

This should resolve the issue and allow you to build the project successfully with React Native 0.71.12.

Comment: I tried this but its not fixed. same issue